# PHP would this be risky (using hackable data for includes)

Tags: php

```
mysql_select_db($db.'_'.$table);    
include("/home/site/includes/".$type."/functions.php");
```

Would this be a bad idea if $table and $type are values passed via ajax from a JS script?

And this..

```
$function($args);
```

If the value for $function is passed via ajax?

Answer (score 1):

Very risky.

The first could be used to perform operations on the wrong database, possibly bypassing access restrictions (I don't *think* it could access the MySQL internal database because of the underscore, but I could be wrong).  The second could be manipulated to access any "functions.php" file in the filesystem, and if you also permit file uploads, this could allow unrestricted code injection.  I don't know enough about PHP to know the full range of code injection permitted by the third example, but it looks highly dangerous (eg. passing a function of "system").

**Edit:**
The correct way to deal with user input is to develop a whitelist that describes "known safe" input.  In the case of `$function`, that means a list of acceptable function names; for `mysql_select_db`, a list of values for `$table` that the user is permitted to access.  If you see an invalid value for user input, reject the entire transaction with a suitably vague error message.  Anything else is just inviting problems from attackers who are cleverer than you.

Comment: how about if I included an underscore in the function names so they are made up from two variables separated by the underscore?

Comment: for the database would having a lookup table in php stop any problems, so at least I am restricting the tables that may get selected?

Comment: If you force an underscore into the function name, the attacker will just pass "shell" and "exec" as the variables.

Comment: good point, maybe another delimiter e.g do_func_this where do & this are user inputted?

Comment: Are you willing to bet your security on the assumption that PHP does not and never will have a built-in or library function that follows that naming pattern?

Comment: I can come up with a pattern that will work, but I'm not going post here lol. Other than spoofing an existing function this is ok though?